# FFMPEG : Add video (partial video effect) under the image with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a video, `video.mp4`, and an image, `artwork.png`

I would like, to use FFmpeg:

- To display the `video.mp4` effect inside the image `artwork.png`
- If possible, resize `output.mp4` as per the demo `demo_output.mp4`

Is this possible?

Resources: https://www.dropbox.com/transfer/AAAAAGgUAt5aTw0W5DYH75y-CvJTKQUqxXatnMPNjHBxpz4DDiOH9IM

Have tried :
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i artwork.jpg -filter_complex '[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ckout][vid];[vid][ckout]blend=all_mode='lighten'[out]' -map '[out]' output.mp4`

Comment: Will look at it tomorrow. Ping if no answer.

Comment: @Gyan yet no answer was found

Answer (score 0):

You would use scale2ref to match the fx clip with the artwork and then the blended result with the demo reference. For correct results, blend will have to work with RGB inputs, so those inputs have to be converted first.

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i artwork.jpg -i video.mp4 -i demo_output.mp4 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[fx][bg];[bg]format=gbrp[bg];[fx]format=gbrp[fx];[fx][bg]blend=all_mode=lighten[mix];[mix][2]scale2ref[v][ref];[v]setsar=1[v];[ref]nullsink" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map [v] out.mp4`